# Start failed for Job error in SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, scheduled-tasks, jobs, sql-server-agent

I am trying to schedule a job which executes stored procedure but it is failing. If I try to run it manually, I am getting this error.

[image: Job ran manually throwing error]

At the moment I am trying to run `EXECUTE storedproc` but it takes long time to complete.

Kindly let me know how to avoid this.

Thanks, Ar

Answer (score 1):

This should help but the status of the job should be visible in SQL Server Agent-> Job Activity Monitor

Replace your SQL with something like this:

```
DECLARE
@JobStatus INT
, @AttWarehouse UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = (
                                   SELECT TOP 1
                                        [S].[job_id]
                                    FROM
                                        [msdb]..[sysjobs] AS [S]
                                    WHERE
                                        [S].[name] = 'AttendanceWarehouse'
                                 )

SELECT
    @JobStatus = [run_status]
FROM
    [msdb]..[sysjobhistory]
WHERE
    [job_id] = @AttWarehouse
    AND [run_status] = 4
PRINT @JobStatus
IF @JobStatus <> 4
BEGIN
    EXEC [msdb]..[sp_start_job]
        @job_id = @AttWarehouse
END
```